# How did Spider-Man get his powers in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

I am a fan of Spider-Man. But for the new Spider-Man (Tom Holland) version, I don't remember seeing a scene about how he got his powers. Is there a scene for it? If so, which movie is it?

Comment: [Asked and answered on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212242/98028).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## He was bitten by a (radioactive?) spider

...we just don't see it onscreen,

[**This Q&A on Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212242/is-there-ever-any-indication-in-the-mcu-as-to-how-spider-man-got-his-powers) covers it fully but the reasoning for not including it in the movie was..

> > > "We never talked about showing it, because the MO was always to not show anything we've seen before," Watts said. "If anything ever felt slightly familiar, to try to figure out if there's a way to avoid it or tackle it in a different way. But that was something that definitely felt like we've seen that before."
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > By now, a third Uncle Ben death in cinema in less than 20 years would be redundant. "That's why," Feige said, regarding the choice to skip the scene in Spider-Man: Homecoming. "You didn't really have to ask," Pascal added.
> >
> > <sub>[Comicbook, Uncle Ben And The Spider Bite Were Never Considered For Spider-Man: Homecoming](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/06/26/why-isnt-uncle-ben-in-spiderman-homecoming-/)</sub>

Comment: That was a freebie..

Comment: Who are these people that are supposedly interviewed in this excerpt?

Comment: Jon Watts, director of Homecoming. Amy Pascal, producer of Homecoming. Kevin Feige, President of Marvel Studios

Answer (score 3):

One of the few times a studio has done something right in my opinion.

Spiderman’s origins are part of society's pop culture. *Everybody* knows his origin. It's been shown a thousand times.

Though one could argue that very young generations might not know, thus a scene should be warranted.

Homecoming completely ignores it and just goes straight into telling their story and delegates his origin to a single line while talking to Ned.

> Peter: The spider’s dead, Ned.

Which is not only a nice quick thing to get over the scene, it has a nice symbolism that the spider and his origin *doesn’t matter at all.*